# Intento hacer que mi bot elimine canales en un bucle

Tags: python, discord.py

he querido hacer un bot que elimine canales hechos por una raid, para mis amigos ya que han sufrido mucho de eso, es decir le han hecho muchas raid

Mi problema es el siguiente, no puedo hacer que el bot elimine varios canales, la maximo que se puede hacer es eliminar 1, pero yo quiero que elimine canales por su name_channel y no por su id_channel, he intendo hacerlo con for y while pero sigue eliminando 1, alguna ayuda please?

He intentado buscar por internet, ademas de usar mi creatividad para eliminarlos mediante bucles como el for y el while, pero de ninguna forma pude hacerlo

Lo que esperaba es que se pudieran eliminar todos los canales hecho por el mismo nombre

```
from nextcord.ext import commands
from get_token import Token
from time import sleep
import asyncio


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=nextcord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"El Bot {client.user} esta activo")

@commands.has_any_role("Mod")
@client.command( aliases=["clearC","removeC","deleteC"])
async def c(ctx, *Channels: nextcord.TextChannel):
   for ch in Channels:
      await ch.delete()

@commands.has_any_role("Mod")
@client.command( aliases=["clearV","removeV","deleteV"])
async def v(ctx, *, Channels: nextcord.VoiceChannel):
   for c in Channels:
      c.delete()
client.run(f"{Token}")
```

---

Codigo del problema:

```
import nextcord
from nextcord.ext import commands
from get_token import Token
from time import sleep
import asyncio
import re


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=nextcord.Intents.all())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"El Bot {client.user} esta activo")

@commands.has_any_role("Mod")
@client.command( aliases=["clear","remove","delete"])
async def delete_multiple_channels(ctx, channel_name):
    channels = [channel for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels if channel.name == channel_name]
    for channel in channels:
        await channel.delete()
client.run(f"{Token}")
```

Comment: `nextcord.VoiceChannel` y `nextcord.TextChannel` parecen ser tipos de elementos individuales. Deberían ser listas para poder usar el for sobre ellos.

Comment: prueba `nextcord.get_all_chanels()` para coger todos los canales [info](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.Client.get_all_channels)